# AngularJS uiSortable - highlighting table cell moving over with item and mouse

Tags: angularjs, jquery-ui-sortable

I use uiSortable ([uiSortable](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-sortable)) in my application and it works fine.
The only thing I was not able to do is to highlighting the drop cell before leave the item into the cell.
This is my html- code:

```
<td ui-sortable="vm.moveableItems" data-ng-model="myModelItems">
    ....
```

and this is my javascript code:

```
vm.moveableItems= {
        start: function(e, ui) {
        },
        update: function(e, ui) { 
        },
        stop: function(e, ui) {
             // code to place the item into the cell -> works fine
```

Is there a possibility to highlight the cell I move over with the item and the mouse?

Comment: can you please post a fiddle?

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for `placeholder: <classname>`. 
This gets set in your `ui-sortable=<parms>`, alongside the `start`, `update` and `stop` methods you're already using.

---

#### Demo http://plnkr.co/edit/s3LNeq4SzrBxj4bhFu4q?p=preview

#### Controller

```
app.controller('mainController', function ($scope) {

    $scope.list = ['Alabama','Alaska','Arizona','Arkansas'];

    $scope.sortableOptions = {
        placeholder: 'ui-state-highlight'
        start: function(e, ui) {},
        update: function(e, ui) {},
        stop: function(e, ui) {},
    };

});
```

#### Markup

```
<div ng-controller="mainController">
  <table class="table">
    <tbody ui-sortable="sortableOptions" ng-model="list">
      <tr ng-repeat="item in list" style="cursor: move;">
        <td>
          {{item}}
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
.ui-state-highlight {
    height: 50px;
    background: green;
    display: block;
}
```

#### Update:Horizontal

This is also possible to do with horizontal movement. Pass `'ui-floating': true`, and tweak your css to support it. Plnkr of this implantation here: http://plnkr.co/edit/YwBpL0LmSvVaa4t2HNsO?p=preview

Comment: is it also possible to do it horizontal as well, e.g. with two td in tr?

Answer (score 1):

*uiSortable* is  by default already applying the `ui-sortable-placeholder` class to the element you are currently hovering.

By default, it's invisible, but you can easily change it using only css:

```css
.ui-sortable-placeholder {
  visibility: visible !important;
  background: red;
}
```

If the element you want to stylize is the `td` instead, just change the `background` of `.ui-sortable-placeholder td`, but keep the `visibility` override on the placeholder class.